# Access sheet using string

Tags: vba, excel

I want to access a sheet in my code. The name of the sheet I want to access is stored in another sheet (SheetA). The sheet I want to access changes depending on what the user enters in SheetA. I therefore store the name of the sheet I want to use (retrieved from sheet A) in a string.

How can I call the sheet I want using a variable string as the name? Here is my piece of code:

```
         Dim temp As String
         sheetName = .Cells(counter, 3)' this is a cell in Sheet A containing the name of my next sheet

         With Sheets(sheetName) 'ERROR HERE ************
          Do While valueT(counter + 1) > .Cells(counter4, 1)   
            colletM(counter) = .Cells(counter4, 1)
            counter4 = counter4 + 1
          Loop
         End With
```

Thought of putting all the sheet names in order in an array, comparing the string I want as a sheet name (tempo) to the sheet names in the array and selecting the index of the sheet I need, but you could also suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, the only reason I can see for the error is the worksheet name in the variable sheetName doesn't exist in this workbook.